apt-get update does not list the number of packages to be upgraded like apt
When I run sudo apt update, at the end I receive the info:
10 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.

With sudo apt-get update, I don't receive that message. How do I add that text?

Is there any reason why you can't call apt directly, if you like its behavior?

There isn't a reason. I am just curious.

Isn't it quite a weird question then? apt is a more user-friendly version of apt-get, and it's being user-friendly by adding that message, so why not just use it?

That's another good answer.

There is no way to get that exact message with apt-get. The closest that you get with apt-get is something similar with the following command:
apt-get --simulate upgrade | grep "upgraded.*newly installed"

That will output the following for which the number of packages may be different on your system:
47 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

You can run it without the pipe into grep to get the full list but I added that to only include output that is the most synonymous with the desired output from apt update. That doesn't give the same output but it does effectively give the same information.

This is quite useful. How can I run the command every time I run sudo apt-get update?

@horsey_guy You can't. apt-get update doesn't give that output.

While on the surface, apt and apt-get seem very similar, they are not, although likely apt calls apt-get underneath.
The apt command was created specifically to add user facing features (exactly like this one) for a better user experience, where the apt-get interface is kept clean and stable for extended compatibility to be used in scripts.
